# asp.net json .net objects

Tags: asp.net

I have this class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace TestConnect
{
    public class UserInfo
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string picture { get; set; }
        public string bio { get; set; }
        public string quotes { get; set; }
        //public HometownInfo from { get; set; 
        public From hometown { get; set; }
        public string relationship { get; set; }
        public string gender { get; set; }
        public List<Education> data { get; set; }
     }

    public class Education
    {

        public From school { get; set; }
        public From year { get; set; }
        //public From [] concentration { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }

    }

}

public class HometownInfo
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string homename { get; set; }
}
```

Now trying to do

```
url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=education&access_token=" + oAuth.Token;
json = oAuth.WebRequest(oAuthFacebook.Method.GET, url, String.Empty);
Education edu = js.Deserialize<Education>(json);
```

`foreach(Education_history edu_history in Education.data)` gives an error

> Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object. Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during
>   the execution of the current web
>   request

Thanks 
User

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting breakpoints at the various steps in your code and seeing where it might be?

somewhere else in your code you must be declaring url and json?

does js.Deserialize() create a new object or are you missing this
Education edu = new Education();

Also if its in a web application make sure that your code is placed in the correct page events so that they happen in the correct order